# MongoDB - join multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query, left-join

I want to join (left) multiple collection:

Step1:

```
db.user.insertOne({

    user_id: "id_user_1",

})
```

Step2: (add first document to each colection - id_user_1)

```
db.est_zone.insertOne({

    zone: {
        temp: "tempo1",
    },
    user_id: "id_user_1"

})

db.est_tax.insertOne({

    tax: {
        fam: "fam1",
    },
    user_id: "id_user_1"

})
```

Step3: (add second document to each colection - id_user_1)

```
db.est_zone.insertOne({

    zone: {
        temp: "tempo2",
    },
    user_id: "id_user_1"

})

db.est_tax.insertOne({

    tax: {
        fam: "fam2",
    },
    user_id: "id_user_1"

})
```

So, when i use $lookup (aggregate) with just one collection, it work like what i expect:

```
db.user.aggregate([

    {
    $match: {
      user_id: "id_user_1"
    }},
    
    {
    $lookup: {
      from: "est_zone",
      localField: "user_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "est_zone"
    }},
    
    {$unwind: "$est_zone"},

])
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d4"
    },
    "user_id": "id_user_1",
    "est_zone": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d5"
      },
      "zone": {
        "temp": "tempo1"
      },
      "user_id": "id_user_1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d4"
    },
    "user_id": "id_user_1",
    "est_zone": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63db1ad58c3dc65723ce0ac9"
      },
      "zone": {
        "temp": "tempo2"
      },
      "user_id": "id_user_1"
    }
  }
]
```

tempo1 and tempo2 are in one document.

i expect fam1 in tempo1 document

and fam2 in tempo2 document

but, when i use lookup for join the "est_tax" it doesnt works like i want (even if use $unwind):

```
db.user.aggregate([

    {
    $match: {
      user_id: "id_user_1"
    }},
    
    {
    $lookup: {
      from: "est_zone",
      localField: "user_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "est_zone"
    }},
    
    {$unwind: "$est_zone"},
    {
    $lookup: {
      from: "est_tax",
      localField: "user_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "est_tax"
    }},

])
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d4"
    },
    "user_id": "id_user_1",
    "est_zone": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d5"
      },
      "zone": {
        "temp": "tempo1"
      },
      "user_id": "id_user_1"
    },
    "est_tax": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d6"
        },
        "tax": {
          "fam": "fam1"
        },
        "user_id": "id_user_1"
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63db1ad58c3dc65723ce0aca"
        },
        "tax": {
          "fam": "fam2"
        },
        "user_id": "id_user_1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d4"
    },
    "user_id": "id_user_1",
    "est_zone": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63db1ad58c3dc65723ce0ac9"
      },
      "zone": {
        "temp": "tempo2"
      },
      "user_id": "id_user_1"
    },
    "est_tax": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d6"
        },
        "tax": {
          "fam": "fam1"
        },
        "user_id": "id_user_1"
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63db1ad58c3dc65723ce0aca"
        },
        "tax": {
          "fam": "fam2"
        },
        "user_id": "id_user_1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What i expect:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d4"
    },
    "user_id": "id_user_1",
    "est_zone": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d5"
      },
      "zone": {
        "temp": "tempo1"
      },
      "user_id": "id_user_1"
    },
    "est_tax": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d6"
        },
        "tax": {
          "fam": "fam1"
        },
        "user_id": "id_user_1"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63db1a68ef527b03093e78d4"
    },
    "user_id": "id_user_1",
    "est_zone": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63db1ad58c3dc65723ce0ac9"
      },
      "zone": {
        "temp": "tempo2"
      },
      "user_id": "id_user_1"
    },
    "est_tax": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63db1ad58c3dc65723ce0aca"
        },
        "tax": {
          "fam": "fam2"
        },
        "user_id": "id_user_1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

on the output:

first document must have only tempo1 and fam1

second document mst have only  tempo2 and fam2

i new in mongoDB and still thinking like SQL,

I am open to suggestions, i read there's no problem with duplicate data (mb in user, idk)

but, i need to keep separate "est_zone" and "est_tax"

Thx for yout time!

Comment: There is no key to join between `est_zone` and `est_tax`. You need some key field to link them up and to separate the records when `$lookup`

Comment: You mean, 
$lookup: est_zone and est_tax = est_zone_tax
and then 
$lookup: user and est_zone_tax?

Comment: no. `est_zone` only have connection to `user` now. Same for `est_tax`. You need to have some key field to indicate connection between `est_zone` and `est_tax`. One of the examples would be like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/48Djkbxox_Z). Note the new field `tax_id` that link up between `est_zone` and `est_tax`